# rails: NoMethodError in production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, production-environment

I am on hour 12 of programming, so i might be overlooking something simple, but any suggestions on this issue?

in my app_helper i added a module for a redcarpet filter with haml

```
module Haml::Filters::Redcarpet
  include Haml::Filters::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

  def render(text)
    options = [:autolink, :smart, :hard_wrap, :no_intraemphasis]
    content_tag(:div, Redcarpet.new(text.to_s, *options).to_html.html_safe, :class => "markup" )
  end
end
```

works great in development.  but in production, it's throwing

```
[ !EXCEPTION! ] NoMethodError: undefined method 'content_tag' for Haml::Filters::Redcarpet:Module
```

why would that be?  or what can i check?  i even ran the console on production and was able to include TagHelper and use those methods.  puzzled...

Comment: Please post both your /config/environments/production.rb and development.rb files - there may be a difference between the two environments, causing the issue.

Comment: i put up a pastie with the 2 configs. http://pastie.org/2142973

Comment: Also, development environment is OSX/WEBrick and production is Debian/Passenger

Comment: Is the version of Rails the same on both development and production machines?

Comment: so i set cache_classes to false, now it works.  why would caching my classes prevent that helper from being included?

Comment: Did you restart your web server after deploying the change that included the statement "include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper"? If your classes were cached, and if I remember this correctly, you need to restart your web server to get code changes such as new "include" statements.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have different versions of one or more gems on your production box from your dev environment.  Do "gem list" in both and add the results to your original post.

The best way to avoid this problem is to use the Ruby Version Manager (RVM) and the 'bundler' gem: you can create a gemset specific to your project and thus ensure that the gems are exactly the same for both versions (prod & dev) of the project.

rvm: https://rvm.io

bundler: http://gembundler.com/

Oh - and if you look down your stack trace you will probably see a reference to the gem that sets up the haml/redcarpet stuff, this is probably the culprit, ie has a different version.